# Movie Recommendation Engine using Naive Bayesian classification & R

Tags: recommendation-engine

Could any one help me to understand if it is possible to have Recommendation engine with Naive Bayesian.
Please help me by providing site/documentation on this.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to prepare a dataset with crawling your desired source. Then, you should check  your dataset for some errors. After that, selecting some features process starts. This is for what kind of recommendation do you desire, based on your dataset. Then, you are ready to apply some generic classification or regression algorithms. At this point you can either choose implementation of algorithms in your code with R or Python etc. or, you can use tools like WEKA for this process. The tools and dataset that you can use are here.

1. Weka - Weka is tool that gathers some algorithms to solve data mining problems. It is developed at the University of Waikato, New Zealand. Ther is a basic example of the process is [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/use-machine-learning-algorithms-weka/).
2. [MovieLens Project](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/) - MovieLens is a project under the organization of GroupLens. There are some datasets about movies.
3. Kaggle IMDB 5000 Movie Dataset - Kaggel is a crowdsourced organization for producing datasets to Data Science Community. Kaggle has some datasets with varying sizes.